# How to upload multiple files to multiple storage with Multer s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I' ve seen many questions about to upload multiple files with Multer and by my side it is working, now my question is if **is it possible to upload multiple files with Multer to different storages?** Currently I am uploading the files to a bucket in S3, now I want to upload the same files in both bucket#1 and bucket#2 in S3 in the same request.

This is my current code to upload multiple files with Multer S3

```
const uploadsBusinessGallery = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3.s3_BUCKET_TEST,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_BUCKET_TEST,
    acl: "public-read",
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      const pathForder = req.url.split("/");

      var newFileName =
        path.basename(file.originalname, path.extname(file.originalname)) +
        path.extname(file.originalname);
      var fullPath =
        pathForder[pathForder.length - 1].replace("%20", " ") +
        "/" +
        newFileName;
      console.log(fullPath);
      cb(null, fullPath);
    },
  }),
  /*   limits: { fileSize: 2000000 }, // In bytes: 2000000 bytes = 2 MB
   */ fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
}).array("galleryImage", 500);
```

As you can see, currently I'm uploading the files to a bucket called **AWS_BUCKET_BUCKET_TEST**, I want to upload the same files to a second bucket in S3.

I have tried that after uploading the files in AWS_BUCKET_BUCKET_TEST (bucket#1), I use the same request to upload them to the second bucket:

**My idea is once multer uploads the files to bucket#1, send the same request to a multer to upload the files to a second bucket**

```
function uploadFiles(req, res) {
  uploadsBusinessGallery(req, res, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("errors en la integración", error);
      return;
    } else {
      // If File not found
      if (req.files === undefined) {
        console.log("Error: No File Selected!");
      } else {
        // If Success
        integration(req,res);
      }
    }
  });
```

```
const integration = (req, res) => {
    uploadsFilesIntegration(req, res, (error) => {
    console.log("*********************************");
    console.log("Backend integration");
    if (error) {
      console.log("errors en la integración", error);
      return;
    } else {
      // If File not found
      if (req.files === undefined) {
        console.log("Error: No File Selected!");
      } else {
        // If Success
        console.log('Archivos integrados')
      }
    }
  });
};
```

**Multer that uploads files to bucket#2 called AWS_BUCKET_CD**

```
const uploadsFilesIntegration = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3.s3_CD,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_CD,
    acl: "public-read",
    contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      const pathForder = "folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3";
        console.log('s3.s3_CD',s3.s3_CD)
      var newFileName =
        path.basename(file.originalname, path.extname(file.originalname)) +
        path.extname(file.originalname);
      var fullPath =
        pathForder +
        "/" +
        newFileName;
      console.log(fullPath);
      cb(null, fullPath);
    },
  }),
  /*   limits: { fileSize: 2000000 }, // In bytes: 2000000 bytes = 2 MB
   */ fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
}).array("galleryImage", 500);
```

However, It seems when Multer uploads the files to bucket#1, it modifies the request what makes that Multer does not upload the files to bucket #2.

I've tried clonning the request to send different request to the different multers but I couldn't do it. Also, I thought that I can add more than one storage to a single multer, but I couldn't figure out the way.

**Can someone help me please. Thanks.**

PD: Both multer uses the same fieldName, cause I want to upload the same files to both multer.